# Comment traduire « ugh » et montrer le dégoût ?

Tags: interjections

Qu’est-ce qu’on utilise pour dire « ugh » et pour dire des trucs comme *« Ughhhh, that’s really stupid! »* et d’autres moyens d’en montrer le dégoût ?

Answer (score 5):

> [Pouah](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pouah) !
>  [Beurk](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beurk) ! (surtout avec la nourriture)
>   [Ark](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ark#Fran%C3%A7ais) ! (au Québec)
>  [Ouach(e)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouache#Interjection)/[ouak](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouak)/[yak](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak#Interjection)/[yach(e)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/yache) ! (au Canada)
>  [Ouark/wark](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouark) ! (au
>   Canada)
>  [Dégueu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9gueu) ! (adjectif, abréviation de
>   dégueulasse)
>
> [ Dénichés sur [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Page_d%E2%80%99accueil). ]

Comment: du coup « pouah c’est trop relou ce type » marcherait ?

Comment: On dirait alors "pouah *il* est trop relou ce type"... mais "pouah" et les autres mots cités expriment un dégout envers quelque chose ou quelqu'un de physiquement sale, ou quelque chose ayant une odeur ou un gout insupportable. C'est assez incongru de l'utiliser avec *relou*, qui est un jugement sur quelqu'un qui a un comportement difficile à supporter. On entendra plutôt "pouah il est dégueu, ce type", ou "pouah, il me dégoûte, ce type". Une autre variante régionale pour la Belgique (que je ne trouve pas dans le wiktionnaire, mais qui est un belgicisme attesté): *bèkes*.

Comment: En y repensant: on peut aussi dire "pouah" ou "beurk" (je ne m'avance pas pour les expressions québecoises) pour exprimer son dégoût de quelqu'un de *moralement* "sale". Ex: "Pouah, ce politicien pourri me dégoûte".

Comment: @Greg J'ai répondu davantage en fonction du titre et de l'équivalence trouvée au Wiktionnaire qu'en fonction de l'exemple. D'autres réponses peuvent peut-être explorer ce qui est antéposé à _that’s really stupid!_ dans l'exemple. Spontanément pour moi ce serait le juron + _que_. Je sais pas trop.

Answer (score 2):

Pour les expressions de dégoût, voir l'autre réponse.

Par contre *ugh* dans l'exemple donné (*ughh, that's really stupid*) reflète plutôt l'énervement que le dégoût. Du coup, en français je préférerais quelque chose comme

> Rhaa, c'est vraiment nul
>
> Putain, c'est vraiment con *(more vulgar)*
>
> Naan, mais comme c'est trop stupide